# How to add "View more results" kind of functionality in my PHP based website?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to make a website which will recommend users books according to the genre selected by them. I am using PHP, JavaScript and mySQL.

The problem is that there will me almost more than 100 books for a particular genre. I want to display only 10 books at a time and subsequent next 10s to be viewed after clicking a link/button/whatever mentioning -"Next 10 recommendations".

Please tell me what code should I use. Or is there any workaround for it? (what Facebook uses for it (Older posts) link in the bottom of every wall?)

Comment: You'll need to use Ajax for that, but before that you'll need to do your own search on the field and display something here.

Comment: How many results do you reasonably expect? Do you limit them? I'd also consider "View all" or allow users to set a preference. Forcing me to page 10 at a time means I'll go elsewhere because I find it irritating

Comment: You will need to use AJAX and a little bit of JavaScript to implement it. This question is a little vague; I suggest trying something first, and coming back to SO with any particular problems you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963766/pagination-in-php)

Comment: You **don't** need to use Ajax, regular links will work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$offset = 0;
if (isset($_GET['offset'])) {
   $offset = abs($_GET['offset']);
}
$where = '';
if (isset($_GET['genre'])) {
   $where = "WHERE genre='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['genre'])."'";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books $where LIMIT $offset,10"
// get your data

$offset += 10;
$genre = urlencode($genre);
echo "<a href='?genre=$genre&$offset=$offset'>Get more</a>";
```