# If I already have a table of tickets set up to split into pages, how can I make it have page links at the bottom?

Tags: php, pagination

> **This question is answered. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465147/if-i-already-have-a-table-of-tickets-set-up-to-split-into-pages-how-can-i-make-i/7506858#7506858) to see the answer that answered my question.**

---

### Edit:

I still don't know exactly how to do this. Could someone help? I get the fact that it's called "pagination" but I don't know how to make it display page links at the bottom. I hope someone will be able to help.

---

I have a table of tickets and all of the data is loaded in from a database to the table. I have pages on it (using `?page=1`, `?page=2`, etc.) but, how can I make it where it has "Next Page", "Previous Page", "Last Page", "Page *something* of *something*", etc. at the bottom?

#### The code that does it all is:

```
<table id="tickets">
 <tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Email</th>
 <th>Subject</th>
 <th>Created on</th>
 <th style="width:65px;">Status</th>
 <th>Actions</th>
 </tr><?php
$startpoint = $_GET["page"];
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $startpoint = $_GET["page"];
}
else {
    $startpoint = 1;
}
$startpoint = $startpoint - 1;
$startpoint = $startpoint * 10;
$endpoint = $startpoint + 10;

function addEllipsis($string, $length) {
    $end = "...";
    if (strlen($string) > $length) {
        $length -= strlen($end); // $length =  $length – strlen($end);
        $string = substr($string, 0, $length);
        $string .= $end; //  $string =  $string . $end;
    }
    return $string;
}
$x = 1;
if ($show == "active") {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE is_active='1'");
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $x++;
        $name = $info['name'];
        $email = $info['email'];
        $subject = $info['subject'];
        $ticketid = $info['ticket'];
        $isActive = $info['is_active'];
        $created = $info['created'];
        if ($isActive == '1') {
            $status = "<span class=\"open\">Open</span>";
        }
        if ($isActive == '0') {
            $status = "<span class=\"closed\">Closed</span>";
        }
        if ($x > $startpoint && $x < $endpoint) {
            echo "
 <tr>
 <td>".$name."</td>
 <td>".$email."</td>
 <td title=\"".$subject."\">".addEllipsis($subject, 16)."</td>
 <td>".$created."</td>
 <td>".$status."</td>
 <td><a href=\"/employee/employee.php?ticket=".$ticketid."\">View ticket &raquo;</a></td>
 </tr>";
        }
    }
}
else if ($show == "closed") {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE is_active='0'");
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $x++;
        $name = $info['name'];
        $email = $info['email'];
        $subject = $info['subject'];
        $ticketid = $info['ticket'];
        $isActive = $info['is_active'];
        $created = $info['created'];
        if ($isActive == '1') {
            $status = "<span class=\"open\">Open</span>";
        }
        if ($isActive == '0') {
            $status = "<span class=\"closed\">Closed</span>";
        }
        if ($x > $startpoint && $x < $endpoint) {
            echo "
 <tr>
 <td>".$name."</td>
 <td>".$email."</td>
 <td title=\"".$subject."\">".addEllipsis($subject, 16)."</td>
 <td>".$created."</td>
 <td>".$status."</td>
 <td><a href=\"/employee/employee.php?ticket=".$ticketid."\">View ticket &raquo;</a></td>
 </tr>";
        }
    }
}
else {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tickets");
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $x++;
        $name = $info['name'];
        $email = $info['email'];
        $subject = $info['subject'];
        $ticketid = $info['ticket'];
        $isActive = $info['is_active'];
        $created = $info['created'];
        if ($isActive == '1') {
            $status = "<span class=\"open\">Open</span>";
        }
        if ($isActive == '0') {
            $status = "<span class=\"closed\">Closed</span>";
        }
        if ($x > $startpoint && $x < $endpoint) {
            echo "
 <tr>
 <td>".$name."</td>
 <td>".$email."</td>
 <td title=\"".$subject."\">".addEllipsis($subject, 16)."</td>
 <td>".$created."</td>
 <td>".$status."</td>
 <td><a href=\"/employee/employee.php?ticket=".$ticketid."\">View ticket &raquo;</a></td>
 </tr>";
        }
    }
}
  ?>

 </table>
```

How could I make it show links to the each page (just a simple "1", "2", etc.) at the bottom? I can't create them myself because I wont know how much pages there is and stuff. It would also be great if the link could turn into grey non-clickable text when you are on that certain page. Someone helped me with the page feature but they aren't online right so they can't help me. (I'm not that good at PHP yet) Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: What you want to do is called "pagination". There are various good answers when searching for "php pagination" - worth a try. A good exmple:[Pagination in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6963766)

Comment: @Pekka Oh, thanks! :) I didn't know that it is called "pagination" therefore I didn't know what to search for. Thank you for that link.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still a _little_ confused. What would make the links show depending on how much pages there are? I will try to write it myself but I don't see where to put the link code and stuff.

Comment: @Pekka I still can't figure out how to get the page links to display. (I just want it to say "First Page", "Previous Page", "Next Page", and "Last Page" and then "Page something of something." I don't need it to display all of the pages) I tried using this: http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/pagination.html But I can't get it to work with my code above. The person that helped me with the splitting them into pages doesn't know how to make page numbers display. I'm thinking my current pagination code is not correct and will probably need to be done a different way. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**-edit-**
After chat, the solution that includes adding a `LIMIT` to the query instead of using `$x` to prevent showing certain rows was the following: https://gist.github.com/1233850

---

Run the following code, since it works on its own it may give you an idea:

```
<style>span{background:#ccc;padding:2px 6px;margin:0 2px;}</style>

<?php
    $currentPage = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $totalPages = 5; //this must be fetched from the db

    //define previous and next
    $previous = ($currentPage > 1) ? $currentPage - 1 : false; 
    $next = ($currentPage < $totalPages) ? $currentPage + 1 : false;

    //here we'll save the resulting code
    $pagination = array();
    //first
    $pagination[] = ($currentPage == 1) ? "First" : "<a href='?page=1'>First</a>";
    //previous
    $pagination[] = $previous ? "<a href='?page=$previous'>Previous</a>" : "Previous";
    //current/total
    $pagination[] = "Page $currentPage / $totalPages";
    //next
    $pagination[] = $next ? "<a href='?page=$next'>Next</a>" : "Next";
    //last
    $pagination[] = ($currentPage == $totalPages) ? "Last" : "<a href='?page=$totalPages'>Last</a>";

    //show it
    foreach($pagination as $part){
        echo "<span>$part</span>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. But, how do I fetch the number from the database? Do I use @f1ames' `SELECT count(*) FROM ...`? Also, will this make it something like this: http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/pagination.html (I couldn't get this method to work with mine) I will try adding yours to mine :)

Comment: Yes, you need to do something like what @f1ames showed. One question for you, you have an `if/elseif/else` but it seems the only thing that changes inside is the query and not the table you display later, if that's the case then only change the query inside the `if/elseif/else` and after that put the `while` only once.

Comment: Well, what that is for is so you can show only "Closed" Tickets, "Active" Tickets, and of course All Tickets. You can actually see it here, and if you want to change the page, change `?page=1` in the URL to another number. (at the moment, there's only 2 pages) I am thinking that the whole page feature will need to be done differently, which is fine with me. As long as I can get it to work :) Is the way I'm doing it to show only Closed or only Active tickets the correct way?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. So just put the `while()` loop after all them, and then put only the queries? Good idea, this would make pagination a lot easier to incorporate wouldn't it?

Comment: See here https://gist.github.com/1233741 check the titles, the first is how you currently have it, the second how you could do it, basicaly there's no need to include the while loop printing the table 3 times, just create a variable for the query. One more thing, now that I pay more attention you were trying to use $startpoint to paginate? You have to use the SQL keyword `LIMIT` for that instead, now I see why you didn't know where to go, tell me, how many tickets you wanna show per page?

Comment: *(Forgot to put the **[link to the page](http://weebuild.heliohost.org/employee/ticket_database.php)** in my comment above)* Yeah, someone else wrote that pagination code for me and that's why I couldn't get anything to work with it. I would like 10 tickets to display per page. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Also, after this, is there a way to make it show the most recent ones? As you can see on that page it has a "Created on" field, and when a  ticket is created, it puts the date it was created in a database column. Is there a way to make the most recent show first or would this be too hard? (I'm hoping there's a simple way to do this, such as a SELECT statement value or something.) But the actual pagination is more important than this, so if its simple I will do it and if it is too hard I probably wont.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3678/discussion-between-derp-and-nathan)

Comment: Thanks @f1ames, ended up using an array on this example, the thing we missed when we first saw the question is he was using $x to limit the results instead of using LIMIT in the query, that was making things confusing :P

Comment: @derp I have it set up on the actual page now. It's located [here](http://weebuild.heliohost.org/employee/ticket_database.php?show=all). Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah :) Much better than the test page that I showed you yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, generally it may be done like this:

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
     $currentPage = $_GET["page"];
}
else {
     $currentPage = 1;
}
```

Good start. To get the number of pages you need to count records in db/items per page.

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tickets"); //yop, it's kind of shortcut
$pages = ceil($count/$itemsPerPage);
```

Ok, generate the page numbers for menu(lets say we want sth like "< 1 ... 3 4 5... last >" -> where $curretnPage = 4):

```
$menu = array();  //array indexes are strings to make this clearer, it normally should be $menu[] = $sth; to preserve adding order which is important here
if($currentPage > 1) {
     $menu['previous'] = $currentPage - 1;
}
$menu['first'] = 1;
if($currentPage > 3) {
     $menu['dots'] = 0;         
}
else if($currentPage == 3) {
     $menu['oneBeforeCurrent'] = $currentPage - 1;
     $menu['current'] = $currentPage;
}
else if($currentPage == 2) {         
     $menu['current'] = $currentPage;
}
$menu['oneAfterCurrent'] = $currentPage + 1;
```

... it's getting kind of complicated, maybe there is a better, faster way, but you can see how it can be done(dunno exactly how it "should be done"). It's not complete, but... you know what to do:)
I hope that what you meant, that you can't create menu... If you have array with numbers just loop and create html links with numbers and put "..." insted of 0.

Cheers

Comment: You're missing a `"` at the end of the query when calculating `$count`. What you wrote is pretty much what I do although instead of using an array I use a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) Will this make it show something like "<<FIRST <PREV NEXT> LAST>>"? Also, derp is right - you're missing a `"` ;)

Comment: Thx, I was wondering why syntax coloring did it wrong... now I know, because of missing "