# Show content from database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have table conatining records for different dog breeds , have a page to dispaly dog breeds with name A, I want to show a little description also there, but description field has lot of data , how can i limit it to fixed size when pulling from database and also I want to put read more at the end. http://www.animalswecare.com/Pets/Dogs/a.php

Comment: This needs much more detail. What do you mean by "fixed size"? What is "read more" supposed to do exactly? You may be looking for pagination, e.g. [Pagination in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6963766)

Answer (score 2):

Try the substr function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in SQL rather than get all of the data and then manage it with PHP, use the SUBSTRING function in your sql query:

SUBSTRING(dog_description,0,20) Would give you a 20 character string from the beginning of the line (hence 0,20)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
    $words = explode(" ",$string);
    return implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
}


$content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

echo limit_words($content,20);
```

EDIT.

As suggested by  DaveRandom.

```
function limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
    $words = str_word_count($string, 1);
    return implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
}


$content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

echo limit_words($content,20);
```

Comment: FYI, you can use [`str_word_count()`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) to get an array of all the "words" in a string - it's operation is a little more intelligent than `explode(' ',$string);`, as it counts any whitespace a separator and ignores numerics and floating punctuation