# How can i get the names that i search for, and add a pagination to the results that are present

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

> The list just stayed at ten items with no pagination to get the rest of the other list, this sucks, But thanks Guys, maybe i need more practice i really need this one to be working so i can learn from this one, any way the first code worked, the second works but stops at ten items, you said try the ceil i did with some code that i had already, the next and back and number of pages came up but no list, tried it again no next and back but ten items came up, i'm beginning to get a bit frustrated here.

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"  />
    <title>Residential</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <form method="post" action="index.php?go" id="searchform">
            <input type="text" id="sf" name="name" class="inputtext" >
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sb" alt="Btn" value="GO">
        </form>
    </section>
    <div class="results">
    <?php
        error_reporting(0);
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if(isset($_GET['go'])) {
                if(preg_match("/[A-Z | a-z]+/", $_POST['name'])){    //"/[A-Z | a-z]+/",
$name=$_POST['name'];

                //connect to the database
                $db=mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ('I cannot connect to the database    because: ' . mysql_error()); 

                //-select the database to use
                $mydb=mysql_select_db("residential");
```

> This is the beginning of the changed code

```
//////////pagination////////////

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT userId, FirstName, LastName FROM residentialbackup WHERE     FirstName ='" . $name . "' OR LastName = '" . $name ."'");

//-count results
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($sql);

// Get the value of the last page in the pagination result set
$lastPage = ceil($numrows / $itemsPerPage);

$itemsPerPage = 10;

$page = $_GET['page'];
if (!$page) $page = 1;
$offset = ($page - 1) * $itemsPerPage;

$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT userId, FirstName, LastName FROM residentialbackup WHERE    FirstName = '" . $name . "' OR LastName = '" . $name ."' LIMIT ". $offset . ", ".   $itemsPerPage);

$paginationDisplay = ""; // Initialize the pagination output variable
// This code runs only if the last page variable is ot equal to 1, if it is only 1 page     we require no paginated links to display
if ($lastPage != "1") {
    // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
    $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $page . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;      &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';
    // If we are not on page 1 we can place the Back button
    if ($page != 1) {
        $previous = $page - 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
    } 
    // Lay in the clickable numbers display here between the Back and Next links
$paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';
    // If we are not on the very last page we can place the Next button
    if ($page != $lastPage) {
        $nextPage = $page + 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=' .   $nextPage . '"> Next</a> ';
    } 
}

echo $paginationDisplay;
///////////////pagination end////////////
```

> i'm stuck up to here!

```
//echo "<p>" .$numrows . " results found for " . stripslashes($name) . "</p>"; 
//-create while loop and loop through result set
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
            $FirstName =$row['FirstName'];
            $LastName=$row['LastName'];
            $userId=$row['userId']; 

            //-display the result of the array
            echo "<ul>\n"; 
            echo "<li>" . "<a href=\"index.php?id=$userId\">"  .$FirstName . " " . $LastName . "     </a></li>\n";
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
    else { 
        echo "<p>Please enter a search query</p>";
    }
}
/*
  if(isset($_GET['by'])){
  $name=$_GET['by'];
  include "connectres.php";
  //-query the database table
  $sql="SELECT userId, FirstName, LastName FROM residentialbackup WHERE FirstName LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR LastName LIKE '%" . $name ."%'";
  //-run the query against the mysql query function
  $result=mysql_query($sql); 
  //-count results
  $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
  echo "<p>" .$numrows . " results found for " . $name . "</p>"; 
  //-create while loop and loop through result set
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $FirstName =$row['FirstName'];
$LastName=$row['LastName'];
$userId=$row['userId']; 
  //-display the result of the array
  echo "<ul>\n"; 
  echo "<li>" . "<a href=\"index.php?id=$userId\"> " . $LastName . " " . $FirstName . "     </a></li>\n";
  echo "</ul>";
  }
  }
*/
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $userId=$_GET['id'];
    //connect to the database
    include "connectres.php";
    //-query the database table
    $sql="SELECT * FROM residentialbackup WHERE userId=" . $userId;
    //-run the query against the mysql query function
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
    //-create while loop and loop through result set
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $FirstName =$row['FirstName'];
        $LastName=$row['LastName'];
        $PhoneNumber=$row['PhoneNumber'];
        $Address=$row['Address'];
        //-display the result of the array
        echo "<ul>\n"; 
        echo "<li>" . "<img src=\"../images/person.png\"/>" . $FirstName . " " . $LastName . "   </li>\n";
        echo "<li>" . "<img src=\"../images/tell.png\"/>" . "&nbsp;" . "<a href=tel:" .    $PhoneNumber .  ">" . $PhoneNumber . "</a></li>\n";
        echo "<li>" . "<img src=\"../images/house.png\"/>" . "&nbsp;" . $Address . "</li>\n";
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to paginate using PHP is a frequent question here. You might find [Pagination in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963766/pagination-in-php) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has wildcards in it, remove them to only fetch exact matches

```
$sql="SELECT userId, FirstName, LastName FROM residentialbackup WHERE FirstName ='" . $name . "' OR LastName = '" . $name ."'";
```

You can make a pagination like this:

```
$itemsPerPage = 10;
$page = $_GET['page'];
if (!$page) $page = 1;
$offset = ($page - 1) * $itemsPerPage;

$sql="SELECT userId, FirstName, LastName FROM residentialbackup WHERE FirstName = '" . $name . "' OR LastName = '" . $name ."' LIMIT ". $offset . ", ". $itemsPerPage;
```

Comment: Zolex thank You a mill for answering so quickly, life saver bro, the first part it worked, now i tried the second part but it seems that i may have placed it in the wrong place, where exactly do i put the pagination code. Thanks –

Comment: I placed it after the $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result); code and nothing happend but then i figured it was because the first code you help me with needed to be replaced with that and i did but all that happened was that the list shrunk to ten and i could not go to the rest it was just the ten items on the page!

Comment: One more question... :) How can you paginate before you run the query to know how many pages you'll need? (You need the number of rows before you can decide.)

Comment: do a count query with the same where condition as the real query, divide the count by number of items per page and ceil the value to get the number of pages

Comment: check the code above one more time please that's what i have on my localhost right now. which brings up the right names but only ten items in the list.

Comment: well, you wanted a pagination, a pagination shows only $itemsPerPage items on a single page, which is 10 in my example. of course you have to additionally generate the links to all existing pages like ?page=1, ?page=2 to ?page=$numberOfPages

Comment: Ok i understand that, well i'm adding the additional code and i'm seeing the link but no list are coming up. look at the code above.

Comment: better use SELECT count(*) instead of mysql_num_rows