# Search results group by 10 in each page

Tags: php, search

I have stacked on finding a way to code a php search script which will group results e.g of 10 per page.

e.g page

```
 ______________________________
|           ________           |
| search:  |________| submit   |
|                              |
|                              |
|  ________________________    |
| |                      <-|---|------------<div id=results></div>
| |________________________|   |                         |
|______________________________|                         |
                                                         v
                                                      div which shows the results grouped  
                                                      by 10
```

For example: Suppose that I search images by tag, and for the tag 'love' there are 20 images. How could I show the first 10 results on one page and the last 10 results on another page. (the first page has a link to the second page and visa versa).

Comment: Google for `pagination`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963766/pagination-in-php shows the logic for creating this so-called pagination.

Answer (score 0):

A hint is that the modulo operator is really handy for pagination. It checks the remainder of a division operation, which corresponds to zero for new pages when using it for pagination.

Here's a quick and dirty example of pagination:

```
<?php

$arr = array();
for ( $x = 0; $x < 100; $x += 1 ) {
    $arr[] = $x;
};

$page = 7;
$per_page = 7;
$current_page = 1;
for ( $z = 0; $z < count( $arr ); $z += 1 ) {
    if ( 0 === ( $z % $per_page ) ) {
        $current_page += 1;
    }
    if ( $current_page === $page ) {
        echo "value $z on page $page\n";
    }
}


?>

~$ php pagination.php 
value 35 on page 7
value 36 on page 7
value 37 on page 7
value 38 on page 7
value 39 on page 7
value 40 on page 7
value 41 on page 7
```