# Pagination-How to display the results per page?

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, search-engine

I have already done my scripting to display only 40 results per page,but I cant let the user to see the remaining results in the next page.I am getting the data using Curl operation.

I am not posting the code because it is so lengthy. Please check this  [link](http://www.travelpunk.com/blog/result/?action=search&search_propertyid=&search_from_suggestion=0&searchkeywords=Melbourne,%20Australia&reset=1&search_type=dropdown&city=Melbourne&country=Australia&search_keywords=Or%20type%20a%20city%20or%20property%20name&propType%5B%5D=HOSTEL&propType%5B%5D=GUESTHOUSE&propType%5B%5D=HOTEL&propType%5B%5D=APARTMENT&propType%5B%5D=CAMPSITE&date_from=07%20Oct%202013&NumNights=3&guests=2&group_type=#)

So,How can I display the remaining results on the next page?

Sorry,if there is any mistake in my Question. Thank you

```
 if($search_results['api']['status']=="Success")
{

$inc= 1;
$ert = $search_results['result']['Properties'];

if($sortby=='Name'){


foreach ($ert as $name) {
    $names[] = $name['name'];

}
array_multisort($names, SORT_ASC, $ert);
}

if($sortby=='OverallRating'){


foreach ($ert as $name) {
    $names[] = $name['avgRating'];

}
array_multisort($names, SORT_NUMERIC,SORT_DESC, $ert);
}

if($sortby=='Price'){


foreach ($ert as $name) {
    $tuti = array_keys($name['bedPrices']['cheapestPrivate']);

    // echo $name['bedPrices']['cheapestPrivate'][$tuti[0]];
    $names[] = $name['bedPrices']['cheapestPrivate'][$tuti[0]];

}
array_multisort($names, SORT_NUMERIC,SORT_ASC, $ert);
}



// var_dump($ert['bedPrices']);




                    foreach($ert as $hostels)
                    {
if($inc>$page_limit){
    continue;
}

                        if(!((int)$hostels['avgRating'] >= (int)$min_rate && (int)$hostels['avgRating'] <= (int)$max_rate))
                            continue;
                        if(!((int)$hostels['bedPrices']['cheapestPrivate']['USD'] >= (int)$min_pricing && (int)$hostels['bedPrices']['cheapestPrivate']['USD'] <= (int)$max_pricing))
                            continue;
                        if(!(in_array($hostels['type'],$properties_zan_array)))
                            continue;
                            // var_dump($hostels);
                            $arry_hostel = (array) $hostels;
                            foreach ($arry_hostel['roomTypes'] as $hkey => $hvalue) {


                            if(arrayInString($roomtype_zan_array,$hvalue['description'])){



                            echo $hostels[0]['ResultCount'];

                        ?>
                        <?php $propNum1 =$hostels['number']; ?>
                        <div class="search_result">
                <div class="se_img">

                    <div class="top_rated">Top Rated</div> 
                    <form action='hostel-details' method='GET'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='hname' value='<?php echo $hostels['name'];?>'>
                                <input type='hidden' name='city' value='<?php echo "$citi" ;?>'>
                                    <input type='hidden' name='date_st' value='<?php echo "$startdate" ;?>'>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='date_end' value='<?php echo "$enddate" ;?>'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='num' value='<?php echo "$Num" ;?>'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='propnum' value='<?php echo "$propNum1" ;?>'>
                                                    <input type='hidden' name='guestnum' value='<?php echo $guests?>'>

                    <a href='#' onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'>
                        <img src="<?php echo $hostels['images']['0']['url'] ?>" height="80" width="120" class="search_img" title="<?php echo $hostels['name']; ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <span><?php echo $hostels['type']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="se_detail">



                    <form action='hostel-details' method='GET'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='hname' value='<?php echo $hostels['name'];?>'>
                                <input type='hidden' name='city' value='<?php echo "$citi" ;?>'>
                                    <input type='hidden' name='date_st' value='<?php echo "$startdate" ;?>'>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='date_end' value='<?php echo "$enddate" ;?>'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='num' value='<?php echo "$Num" ;?>'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='propnum' value='<?php echo "$propNum1" ;?>'>
                                                    <input type='hidden' name='guestnum' value='<?php echo $guests?>'>
                    <!--<a href="#" onclick='this.parentNode.submit()' style="font-size: 14px;">-->
                    <a href="#"><button style="border: none;"><font style="color:blue">
                    <h2 class="se_title" ><?php echo $hostels['name']; ?></h2>
                    <!--</a> 
                    </form>-->
                    <div class="se_meta"><?php echo $hostels['address1'].", ".$hostels['address2'] ?></div></font></button></a></form>
                        <?php $propNum =$hostels['number']; ?>
                    <!-- <div class="se_warning">Minimum stay of 4 nights for your selected dates</div> -->
                    <div class="se_desc"><?php echo substr($hostels['shortDescription'],0,80)."..." ?> <!-- <a href="#">More Info</a> -->



                <form action='hostel-details' method='GET'>

                            <input type='hidden' name='hname' value='<?php echo $hostels['name'];?>'>
                                    <input type='hidden' name='city' value='<?php echo "$citi" ;?>'>


                                    <input type='hidden' name='date_st' value='<?php echo "$startdate" ;?>'>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='date_end' value='<?php echo "$enddate" ;?>'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='num' value='<?php echo "$Num" ;?>'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='propnum' value='<?php echo "$propNum" ;?>'>
                                                    <input type='hidden' name='guestnum' value='<?php echo $guests?>'>
            <!--            <input type='hidden' name='search_res' value='<?php echo base64_encode(serialize($hostels)); ?>' /> -->
                        <a href='#' onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'>More Info</a>
                </form>

                    </div>

                    <div class="se_review">

                        <?php  if($hostels['avgRating']==0)
                                {
                                    echo '<span style="font-weight:bold;float:left;">No Rating</span>';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo '<div class="se_per">'.$hostels['avgRating']."%".'</div>';
                                }
                        ?>

                        <a href="#">
                                <?php if($hostels['starRating']!='None' &&$hostels['starRating']!=0)
                                        {
                                            echo $hostels['starRating']." Total Reviews";
                                        }
                                    else
                                        echo '<span style="font-weight:bold;"> No Reviews</span>';
                                ?>
                        </a>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="se_compare">
                        <!--<input type="checkbox" class="comp_check"/>
                         <label class="cmp">Compare (0 of 5)</label> -->
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="se_price">
                        <?php if(!empty($hostels['bedPrices']))
                            {
                                if(isset($hostels['bedPrices']['cheapestDorm']))
                                {
                                    foreach($hostels['bedPrices']['cheapestDorm'] as $currency=>$price){
                                        echo    '<div class="do_form">Dorms From</div>';
                                        echo    '<div class="do_price">'.$currency.$price.'</div>';
                                    }
                                }
                                if(isset($hostels['bedPrices']['cheapestPrivate']))
                                {
                                    foreach($hostels['bedPrices']['cheapestPrivate'] as $currency=>$price)
                                    {
                                        echo '<div class="do_form">Privates From</div>
                                                <div class="do_price">'.$currency.$price.'</div>';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ?>

                        <div class="book_btn">
                        <form action='hostel-details' method='GET'>

                            <input type='hidden' name='hname' value='<?php echo $hostels['name'];?>'>
                                    <input type='hidden' name='city' value='<?php echo "$citi" ;?>'>


                                    <input type='hidden' name='date_st' value='<?php echo "$startdate" ;?>'>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='date_end' value='<?php echo "$enddate" ;?>'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='num' value='<?php echo "$Num" ;?>'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='propnum' value='<?php echo "$propNum" ;?>'>
                                                    <input type='hidden' name='guestnum' value='<?php echo $guests?>'>
            <!--            <input type='hidden' name='search_res' value='<?php echo base64_encode(serialize($hostels)); ?>' />-->

                        <a href='#' onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'>Book Now</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>

                        <?php
break;
                            }
                }

                $inc++;
                }
 echo $inc;


            }
```

Comment: There are likely to be a million similar answer to this on SO and Google. Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6963827/894792

Comment: I have searched that too..but i am getting the result using curl operation..

Comment: and you can't limit the cURL result set?

Comment: i can't..if you know please tell me?

Comment: Ok, how is your result set stored?  In an array, an array of objects?  Please can you post the code that you use to loop through the result set to show the items on the page?

Comment: thank you Coulton...it is very lengthy....

Comment: coulton please check the code i have posted

Answer (score 0):

try modifying this php code :

```
// set the number of records to display per page.

$display = 10;

// check if the number of pages has been determined.

if(isset($_GET['$p']) && is_numeric($_GET['$p'])) {
$pages = $_GET['$p'];
}
else {
$q = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_NUM);
$records = $row[0];

// count the number of pages

if($records > $display) { // more than 10 records = 1 page
    $pages = ceil($records/$display);
}
else {
    $pages = 1;
}
} // end of if is set $page

// Determine where in the database to start returning results...eg. page 1 , 2 or 3

if(isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric($_GET['s'])) {
$start = $_GET['s'];
}
else {
$start = 0;
}

// section for displaying links to other pages in table if necessary

if($pages > 1) {
echo '<br/><p>';
$current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

// if it not the first page make a PREVIOUS button
if($current_page != 1) {
    echo '<a href="view_users.php?s='.($start -       $display).'&p='.$pages.'&sort='.$sort.'">Previous</a> ';
}
// make all the numbered pages inside (if current page)

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        if ($i != $current_page) {
            echo '<a href="view_users.php?s='.(($display*($i - 1))).'&p='.$pages.'&sort='.$sort.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
            }
            else {
                echo $i.' ';
            }
    }
// make the NEXT link if not the last page

if($current_page != $pages) {
    echo '<a href="view_users.php?s='.($start + $display).'&p='.$pages.'&sort='.$sort.'">Next</a>';
}
echo '</p>';
}
```